# Drawing quadrant of a circle

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry

I want to draw all the 1/4 of a circle separately but it my window setup, the origin is on top-left(0, 0). Anyway I can get around to **not** invert the screen again?

My current implementation is this:

```
//nX: x
//nY: y
//nR: radius
//verts: std::vector<int>
//indices: std::vector<uint32_t>

verts.push_back(nX + nR); verts.push_back(nY + nR);
for (int i = 270; i >= 360; i -= slice_count)
{
    verts.push_back(nX + cos(DEG_TO_RAD * i) * nR);
    verts.push_back(nY + sin(DEG_TO_RAD * i) * nR);
}


//...
//rest of the code are index manipulation

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &indices[0]);
```

This one will just draw

```
| -   
|      -
|        -
|           -
|             -
|               -
|                -
|                 -
|                  -
|                   -
|____________________
```

It confuses me if I start the rotation from 270 to 360 just to make the above drawing. Any ways you can suggest to ease my confusion? Also it is not logically right, right?

---

Here is the new test code I made.

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex2i(500, 400);
    for (int i = 360; i >= 270; --i)
    {
        int ax = (500 + cos(DEG_TO_RAD * i) * 100);
        int ay = (400 + sin(DEG_TO_RAD * i) * 100);
        glVertex2i(ax, -ay);
    }
glEnd();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the fact that (0, 0) is at the top-left of your screen makes positive X to the right (which is consistent with the usual math representations), but makes positive Y go downwards (which isn't consistent with the usual math representations). If you want to mimic the usual function drawing math's behavior, where a 0º-90º sphere quadrant lies at the top-right side, you could just invert the Y coordinate.

In other words, try:

```
verts.push_back(nY - (sin(DEG_TO_RAD * i) * nR));
```

Comment: mmm there might be other details in the implementation that I can't see with that piece of code. Theorically if you do that the Y coordinate should be switched. If it worked, you should be able to switch to 0 and 90 and still get the same picture.

Comment: Ah! I just put the negative sign in the `sin` function. It works!

Comment: I can accept this as an answer since it is the same. You have just give me a hint but you're the one who solved it. Thanks!

Comment: @h4lc0n Why straight lines from this circle quadrants are not really straight? I mean from 0-90(straight) others not.(90-180, 180-270, 270-360) ? Ah nevermind, its because of GL_TRIANGLE_FAN